# Creating Isolated Points in Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, anchor-point

I noticed that isolated points appear when I import some pictures and made from them the paths (OBJECT >> IMAGE TRACE >> MAKE). Moreover, there is the way to remove stray points: OBJECT >> PATH >>CLEAN UP.

I wonder if it is possible to create isolated points in Adobe Illustrator CS6? How to create them? If not, is there any work around?

Comment: Weird question maybe, but... Why would you want to?

Answer (score 3):

Sure its possible. Use the pen tool click once and exit pen tool (select any other tool, or hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click to clear selection)